# Should return how many letters repeated consecutively 3 times in a string,without using regex...use only core concepts

Tags: java, resolution, puzzle, resolver

Example :

1. If I pass `"BAAABA"` should return 1, as we see that `"A"` is repeated immediate 3 times.
2. When I pass `"BAABAA"` should return 0, as we don't have any letter repeated immediate 3 times.
3. when I pass `"BBBAAABBAA"` should return 2.

Code which I have tried so far:

```
class Coddersclub {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String input = "Your String";
        int result = 0;
        int matchingindex = 0;
        char[] iteratingArray = input.toCharArray();

        for (int matchThisTo = 0; matchThisTo < iteratingArray.length; matchThisTo++) {
            for (int ThisMatch = matchThisTo; ThisMatch < iteratingArray.length; ThisMatch++) {
                if (matchingindex == 3) {
                    matchingindex = 0;
                    result = result + 1;
                }

                if (iteratingArray[matchThisTo] == iteratingArray[ThisMatch]) {
                    matchingindex = matchingindex + 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    matchingindex = 0;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the repetition count (3) is constant why don't you do it with regular expressions? I can provide an example if you like.

Comment: What about BAAAAB? Should that return 0, 1, or 2? And did you mean to have the `c#` tag? And what about BAAABAAA? Should that return 1 or 2?

Comment: @HakanDilek I have provided one such solution using regex, can you validate if that works.

Comment: And what should "AAAAAA" return? Could be 1, 2 or 4 depending on spec.

Comment: BAAAAB - should return 1

Comment: BAAABAAA - return 2

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SOTest {

    final static String regex = "(\\w)\\1*";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String inputString = "aaabbcccaaa";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
        int counter=0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group(0);
            if(group.length()==3) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Group found :: "+group);
            }           
        }
        System.out.println("Total pattern count :: "+counter);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Group found :: aaa
Group found :: ccc
Group found :: aaa
Total pattern count :: 3
```

Comment: I think the result should be the total count of groups of three. In this case it would be 2: 1 for `aaa` one for `ccc`

Comment: This might reduce the coding lines, but i feel it will not increase the logical thinkings....

Comment: yeah, should be the count of total count of groups of three...... AAA- 1, AAABBB-2, AABB-0

Comment: aaabbcccaaa - shoukd return 3 , because we have 'a'  is repeated twice and 'c' once, so total 3

Comment: Ohh okay, I have printed the number of distinct pattern found.. Yes will update the answer

Comment: @jadhu check updated answer its more simple now , since you only need occurrence count I have removed map.

Comment: @jadhu if this answer works for u , will u accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this question with C#, here's a C# solution:

```
public static int CountTriples(string text)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 2; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] == text[i+1] && text[i] == text[i+2])
        {
            ++count;
            i += 2;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

[EDIT]

Someone other than the OP has removed the C# tag that was there when I wrote this answer. I'll leave this here anyway, since the code is trivially convertible to Java.

Comment: `AAAAAA` should  return a count of 2

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash OP has now confirmed this, so I've removed the alternative approaches.